# Send SMS with loop without Contact in Android

Tags: android, loops, sms, contacts

I have a loop which generates phone numbers. After generating the numbers, I want to send a SMS to each number.
The number doesn't exist in phone contacts. I want do all these things in a loop. 
Is it possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible ... what had you tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add this in your loop

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNUmber, null, messageToSend, null, null);
```

and add this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

See more about SmsManager [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#getDefault())